# How to get current state of contract solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, web3js

I am using two contract methods as `getResult` - to get state of contract - and `setNumber(uint num)`- to update current value of state.But every time I call `getResult` method after `setNumber(10)` it returns original value, not the updated one.

Comment: How do you expect people to help you without providing the non-working code?

Comment: In addition to supplying the contract code, you should supply the client side (JavaScript?) code used to set and get the values.

Answer (score 0):

The others are right when they say you should supply code if you want an accurate response. That said, it could be that your problem is you are calling setNumber(10) on your smart contract i.e. myContract.setNumber.call(10). Doing this wont actually update the state of the contract as .call() simply looks up the current state of the chain rather than altering it.